# Недопонимание с кодом

Tags: c, указатели

Наткнулся на код, по которому у меня возникает пару вопросов, если ответите, то буду признателен

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int isOdd(int a) {
    return (a % 2 != 0);
}

unsigned int filter(int *arr, unsigned size, int (*pred)(int), int** out) {
    unsigned i;
    unsigned j;
    *out = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (pred(arr[i])) {
            (*out)[j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    *out = (int*) realloc(*out, j*sizeof(int));
    return j;
}

int main () {
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    unsigned i;
    unsigned size;
    int *aOdd = NULL;

    size = filter(a, 10, isOdd, &aOdd);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", aOdd[i]);
    }

}
```

Вопрос №1:
Зачем требуются явные преобразования такого вида?

```
*out = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
*out = (int*) realloc(*out, j*sizeof(int));
```

Они же излишни, если я не ошибаюсь.

Вопрос №2: Что происходит в строках, которые я выделил восклицательными знаками?

```
    unsigned int filter(int *arr, unsigned size, int (*pred)(int), int** out) {
    unsigned i;
    unsigned j;
    *out = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*size); /* !!!!!!!!!! */
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (pred(arr[i])) {
            (*out)[j] = arr[i]; /* !!!!!!!!!! */
            j++;
        }
    }
    *out = (int*) realloc(*out, j*sizeof(int)); /* !!!!!!!!!! */
    return j;
}
```

Вопрос №3: Разве не легче было реализовать функцию из вопроса №2 таким образом (просто через указатель, а не через указатель на указатель)

```
unsigned int filter(int *arr, unsigned size, int (*pred)(int), int* out) {
    unsigned i;
    unsigned j;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (pred(arr[i])) {
            *(out + j) = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    return j;
}
```

Есть ли существенные различия или даже преимущества между функцией из 
вопроса №2 и функцией из вопроса №3?

Comment: [Подробно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/761117/249284) по первому вопросу

Comment: @Андрей благодарю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Вопрос №1: Зачем требуются явные преобразования такого вида?

Для C не нужны.
Для C++ необходимы, т.к. в C++ неявное преобразование из void* запрещено.

> Вопрос №2: Что происходит в строках, которые я выделил восклицательными знаками?

1) Выделение памяти для size int'ов.
2) Копирование элемента, удовлетворяющего предикату в только что выделенный массив.
3) Отрезаем не заполненный кусок массива данных

> Вопрос №3: Разве не легче было реализовать функцию из вопроса

Они дают разный результат

> Есть ли существенные различия или даже преимущества между функцией из вопроса №2 и функцией из вопроса №3?

Для варианта из вопроса №2 память выделяется непосредственно в функции, а потом усекается. Для варианта из третьего вопроса эта ответственность ляжет на вызывающую сторону. Преимущества и недостатки есть у обоих способов. Всё зависит от того, как их использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Я уже [писал об этом раньше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765254/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B/765259#765259). Когда вы реализуете функцию, размер массива-результата которой заранее неизвестен, т.е. становится известен только внутри функции, то возникает проблема выделения правильного количества памяти для сохранения результата.

Пользователь (т.е. вызывающий код) в общем случае заранее эту память выделить не может, ибо пока еще не знает, сколько памяти понадобится. В таких случаях есть несколько основных стратегий:

1. В некоторых случаях заранее известен максимально возможный размер результата, можно выделить память заранее "по максимуму" и такое максимальное выделение является, условно выражаясь, "разумным".

   Это как раз ваш случай. И да, ваш №3 будет прекрасно работать по этой схеме. Пользователь только обязан предоставить выходной массив размера не менее `size` и иметь в виду, что в общем случае не весь он будет использован.
2. Выделять память внутри функции: либо сразу, когда ее размер становится известен, либо инкрементально по мере накопления результата, либо "по максимуму" с последующим урезанием, либо еще как.

   Это ваш вариант №2.

   Проблема этого подхода в том, что выделение памяти в таком случае нелегко кастомизировать. В простейшем случае будет просто `malloc`, как у вас в примере. А может пользователю не нужен `malloc`?
3. Реализовать функцию по образу и подобию `snprintf`, т.е. предоставить возможность "холостого" прохода, который лишь подсчитывает и возвращает размер результата, но пока не формирует результат.

   Получив подсчитанный размер, пользователь выделяет память любым удобным для него образом и затем снова вызывает ту же функцию, теперь уже для "настоящего" прохода, т.е. для формирования результата в буфере.

То есть ваши №2 и №3 - два альтернативных подхода к решению задачи. Оба способа по-своему правильны.

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Groessmah добавлю пояснение к 3-му вопросу:

Ваша ф-ция реализована ошибочно: во-первых отсутствует выделение памяти - у вас указатель все еще указывает на `NULL`! А для того, чтобы выделить память в ф-ции и нужен указатель на указатель, иначе память выделить вы сможете, но вот сделат так, чтобы нужный нам указатель указывал на нее - нет. Во-вторых, если мы и выделим память до вызова ф-ции, урезать ее в ф-ции, опять таки, не получится.

Comment: ни какой ошибки тут нет... просто ответственность за выделение памяти лежит на вызывающем. По такому же принципу устроены, например, практически все функции стандартной библиотеки.

Comment: ну да, впринципе ты прав, я просто хотел прояснить этот момент

Comment: Я в main() выделил память для реализации функции из 
вопроса №3, просто опустил этот момент, прошу прощения, если ввел в заблуждение

Comment: В `main` вы не могли заранее точно знать, сколько памяти понадобится, и вынуждены были выделять по максимуму - 10 элементов. Это недостаток варианта №3. Но в тоже время в №3 вы могли вообще не использовать `malloc`, а просто сделать `int aOdd[10]`. Это - преимущество варианта №3.